# node.js not running successfully in socioboard api

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

I have successfully Installed Socioboard using the following documentation
https://github.com/socioboard/Socioboard-4.0

2 parts are installed successfully i.e

**Laravel** https://github.com/socioboard/Socioboard-4.0/tree/master/socioboard-web-php

**NodeJs** https://github.com/socioboard/Socioboard-4.0/tree/master/socioboard-api

when I try to run node.js API it's not running at all

Comment: Can you run `php artisan route:list` and post your results please?

Comment: There are 4 nodemon app.js, can you start them one by one and if it doesnt show the usual `service listening on ${port} with ${enivorment} environment` .. can you check the log file and advise what you see .. the log file should be in the public/logs under the name user and date of today.

Comment: @HamzaMohamed  `message: 'Cron setup intialized for monthly user stats...',
  level: 'info',
  timestamp: '2019-10-06T21:12:24.475Z' }
{ message:
   'Mongo issues : failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]',
  level: 'error',
  timestamp: '2019-10-06T21:12:28.803Z' }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the log that you have provided,

> { message: 'Mongo issues : failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]', level: 'error', timestamp: '2019-10-06T21:12:28.803Z' }

you need to make sure that you have installed MongoDB and adding the correct credentials in the

`..config/developemnt.json` file in each one of the four packages `user` `feed` etc.

If you don't have any auth on your MongoDB you can just keep it ass empty string "" for both.

Comment: does socioboard require MongoDB? but there is nothing in the documentation about it.

Comment: yes, they do :) if you checked the error, it is mongodb related